# toggle button event not working on various devices

Tags: android, events, togglebutton, android-event

I am testing my application on various models and I have realized that the toggle button ON and OFF event is not working. This is the list of devices:

Samsung YS5360 
Samsung Galaxy Note 
Samsung S Plus 
HTC Sensation XE 
HTC Wildfire S
Motorola RAZR
LG Optimus Black 
Sony Ericsson Xperia neo V

I am not sure what I am doing wrong as I have followed all Android specifications. These events work on other devices. May I have some help please,anyone?

[RE-EDIT]

This is how I am implementing the listener:

```
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean change) {

        if(change){
            if(text.containsKey("on")){
                // do something
            }
        }else{
            if(text.containsKey("off")){
                // do something
            }
        }
        if(text.containsKey("clicked")){
            // do something
        }
     // }
   }
};
```

I check for both ON and OFF states but this seems not to be working on other devices.

Comment: Any ideas anyone as to how I should proceed?

Comment: You're going to have to post some relevant code, because we have nothing to go off of here.

Comment: Use the debugger and make sure it's not triggering the change on those devices.

Comment: Try installing sample app 'API demos' http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html to the device and check the button functionality in that app first. Otherwise please post some relevant code.

Comment: Can you explain what `text` variable is and how do you set it as it may alter the logic

Comment: Did u find anything common between those devices on which u have this problem...

Comment: Create a sample app with toggle button...n see if it works in those devices

Comment: I am having same issue. In other phone, my toggle works fine, and in my galaxy S3, when I start my app it shows on by default, If I set `toggleBtn.setChecked(true); toggleBtn.setSelected(true);` then also it remains on initially.

Comment: nexus 4 too with several times on moto e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try This Code**

```
    toggle=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tglbtn);
    toggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          if(toggle.isChecked())
          {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The state is changed to on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
            else
            {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The state is changed to off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
             }
             });
```

Answer (score 6):

Using text to know the state of the `ToggleButton` is a bad idea. Use the `isChecked` parameter instead. See its [documentation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html)

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged (CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
        /* checked. ON */
    } else {
        /* unchecked. OFF */
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: will have to see some more related code.. and the layout file.

Comment: Im sorry guys but all your suggestions do not seem to work..I'm at wits end!!